# Left join returns different results than 2 separate tables filtered on same key

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an issue which I can't get my head around:

I have two views in Snowflake: FactEmployee & DimEmployee. The DimEmployee is a slowly changing dimension type 2 and I have added a surrogate key that is also in the fact table. When I left join these views on the surrogate key I get very different results than I expect.

I checked the separate tables by filtering on the surrogate keys for a specific employee and that gives a very different result set. I have attached the images of the anonymized result sets.Below you can find the queries that I am doing to get the join and the filtered result sets.

```
select * from 
    ( select * from "FactEmployeeFte"
      left join "DimEmployee"
      on "DimEmployee"."surrogate_key"="FactEmployeeFte"."surrogate_key" )
      where "employee_name" = 'John Doe'
```

```
select * from "FactEmployee"
where "surrogate_key" in (516, 593, 692, 937, 961, 1305)
```

```
select * from "DimEmployee"
where "surrogate_key" in (516, 593, 692, 937, 961, 1305)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong which I am not seeing?

leftjoin result
[image: leftjoin result]
factemployee
[image: factemployee filtered]
dimemployee
[image: dimemployee filtered]

Answer (score 0):

I think the data you showed in sample is not all the data.

I suggest use single employee to test your left join. If `dimemployee` has only one row for an employee, then there is no way you will get more rows than fact in left join.
Run below SQLs and you will see whats going on.

```
select * from "FactEmployee" where "surrogate_key" in ( 692 )
select * from "DimEmployee" where "surrogate_key" in ( 692)
select * from "FactEmployeeFte"
      left join "DimEmployee"  on "DimEmployee"."surrogate_key"="FactEmployeeFte"."surrogate_key" 
where  "DimEmployee"."surrogate_key" in ( 692)
```

Reason i am saying is, in your left join result, i can see some extra rows which doesnt exist in fact. A join can never create rows. So i think you have more data than you are showing in above sample. So, everything is working fine, data has some issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I performed the queries you showed. They give the same results as I showed in the example (but then the subset for surrogate key 692). 

There is more data yes, but I can't share it because it's sensitive data. 

The current example is about one employee, the reason that the Dim table has more than 1 row is because it is a slowly changing dimension and one employee can have multiple rows in there referring to multiple points in time a certain row was active. This is why there is a surrogate key, this makes the rows unique.

Comment: yes, you need to make it unique first and then join in or join on a date. In your sample, i dont see multiple rows in dim table so i guessed you have more rows.